# Products of Non-Commuting (or orthogonal) Projections

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, noncommutative-algebra, projection-matrices

Let $S=\{P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n\}$ be a set of Hilbert space projections $P_i=P_i^2=P_i^*$ that only commute when they are orthogonal or equal:

$$P_iP_j=P_jP_i\implies P_iP_j=0\text{ or }i=j.$$

Let $i,j,k$ be such that $P_iP_j\neq P_jP_i$ and $P_jP_k\neq P_kP_j$, then I can show that

$$P_iP_jP_k\neq 0.$$

That means that $P_iP_jP_k=0$ only when $P_iP_j=0$ or $P_jP_k=0$.

Is it possible to show this more generally? Or is there a counterexample? To formulate:

> Let $T:=P_{i_1}P_{i_2}\cdots P_{i_k}$ be a product of projections
> from $S$. Then $T=0$ only when some pair $P_{i_m}P_{i_{m+1}}=0$ are
> orthogonal.
>
> True or False?

I can't seem to find any literature that might discuss such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: denote
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 0}, \quad B = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad C = \frac 15 \pmatrix{1&2\\2&4},
$$
and define the block-diagonal projections
$$
P_1 = \pmatrix{A\\&A\\&&0}, \quad P_2 = \pmatrix{B\\ &0\\&&B}, \quad P_3 = \pmatrix{0 \\ & C\\ && C}.
$$
Verify that for each pair $i \neq j$, $P_iP_j \neq P_j P_i$. Nevertheless, we have $P_1P_2P_3 = 0$.

Comment: It won't let me upvote because of my reputation. This is very interesting, I must see where my "proof" for $k=3$ actually goes wrong.

Comment: Ah, I can see there was an additional assumption on my $P_i$... but this is already very useful thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, and I appreciate the thought. If you don't mind, what was the additional assumption?

Comment: I can't really describe it succinctly. On my $S$, there are various three-products that I can say are non-zero. The only ones that have to be checked are $P_iP_jP_k$ with $P_i$ orthogonal to $P_k$. My proof works on $P_iP_j\neq P_jP_i$ and $P_jP_k\neq 0$ and $P_iP_k=0$. I don't even know how to formulate assumptions for a four-product... thought the result might be more general but I can see thank you general doesn't hold at $k=3$.